# В if сравнивать с текстовыми значениями

Tags: php, файлы, сессия, text, if

Форма на сайте получает текст, как сделать чтобы если текст введенный в форме верный(if true) то значения записывались в один файл, а если нет, то в другой. Пока у меня не получилось сделать и оно делает любые значения верными

```
<?php
session_start();
$num = $_SESSION['num'];
if($num = '113b' ||  $num = '113B' ||  $num = '113 b' ||  $num = '113 B') {
$file = fopen("113b.txt","at");
fwrite($file,"$num\n");
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверка - это `==`, присвоение (`=`) возвращает значение (не пустая строка трактуется как `true`).

```
<?php
session_start();
$num = $_SESSION['num'];
if($num == '113b' ||  $num == '113B' ||  $num == '113 b' ||  $num == '113 B') {
$file = fopen("113b.txt","at");
fwrite($file,"$num\n");
fclose($file);
}else{
$file = fopen("Else.txt","at");
fwrite($file,"$num\n");
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: @ilya1099, Тут принято выражать спасибо плюсом и принятием ответа (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Предлагаю чуть упростить код, приведя $_SESSION['num'] в нижний регистр: 
$num = mb_strtolower($_SESSION['num']);
if($num = '113b' ||  $num = '113 b') 
Если используется не UTF8 - то mb_strtolower замените на strtolower

Answer (score 0):

ilya1099, добавлю к ответу выше, что подобные условия выглядят не корректно. Вместо такой записи 
    if ($num == '113b' ||  $num == '113B' ||  $num == '113 b' ||  $num == '113 B') { .. }

было бы лучше использовать такую 
    if (preg_match('~\d{3}\s?[a-z]~i', $num)) { .. }